# Installing Ionic Material Design

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-material

I have followed the steps in integrating Ionic Material Design into an Ionic Project. Below is the list of what I have done:

1. ionic start ionicMaterial blank
2. bower install ionic-material
3. bower install robotodraft
4. Added the JS and CSS libs in out Ionic index.html page
   [image]

On the Fifth it instructs to Inject Ionic Material into your Ionic App like so:
`var app = angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ionic', 'ionic-material']);`

Where and how will I inject it in my Ionic project? I have the app.module.ts and app.component.ts. But how and where do I insert the code mentioned since it even asks me to put in my application name `angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ionic', 'ionic-material'])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below line is for **Ionic 1** framework, it's not for **Ionic 3**.

```
var app = angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ionic', 'ionic-material']);
```

You can add it in app.module.ts as a external module import, if Ionic material is supported in Ionic 3.

Comment: How do I add it in the app.module.ts?

Comment: If you have followed steps from link https://github.com/zachfitz/Ionic-Material. It is only supporting Ionic1, not for Ionic3. Can check README.md